# Combining AND/OR eloquent query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I write following or similar kind of queries using Eloquent?

`SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE (a LIKE %keyword% OR b LIKE %keyword%) AND c = 1 AND d = 5`

I couldn't combine AND/OR in the way I wanted by chaining where & or_where functions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can nest where clauses : http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#nested-where

```
Model::where(function($query)
{
    $query->where('a', 'like', 'keyword');
    $query->or_where('b', 'like', 'keyword');
})
->where('c', '=', '1');
```

This should produce : `SELECT * FROM models WHERE (a LIKE %keyword% OR b LIKE %keyword%) AND c = 1`

Comment: The above statement works if keyword is itself a string. But how do I use the above if keyword is a variable?

Comment: @SUB0DH You can inject the variable into the closures scope with **use**. `function($query) use ($variable)`

Comment: `or_where` should be `orWhere` in 6+

Answer (score 10):

For a more accurate answer to the example:

```
$val = '%keyword%';

A_Table_Model::where(function($query) use ($val)
{
    $query->where('a', 'like', $val);
    $query->or_where('b', 'like', $val);
})
->where('c', '=', 1)
->where('d', '=', 5)
->get();
```

Note: This is Laravel 3 syntax, use camelCase orWhere() for Laravel 4

Comment: In Laravel 4 (at least) you need to use `$val` in parentheses as in the example `A_Table_Model::where(function($query) use ($val)`

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.1+ this will also do the job and looks cleaner:

```
Model::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('a', 'like', 'keyword');
    $query->or_where('b', 'like', 'keyword');
})->where('c', '=', '1')->get();
```

Comment: To somebody who down-voted this - can you explain what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: It wasn't me who down-voted, but anyway: your answer doesn't cover "AND c = 1 AND d = 5" part of the question, so your answer is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `DB::raw()` in the first `where()` to put in the like/or statement.

Comment: Using built in Eloquent methods is much better than this.