# Closures in programmatically generated Eloquent OR queries

Tags: php, closures, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to parse a query string into Eloquent that involves 'OR' statements.
This is part of a much larger function that has other filters etc being applied, but I want to [make an or_where group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659690/530585).

My confusion comes with the closure.. and how to make sure the right values are passed through. If I do as code below, it says the closure has the wrong arguments, but otherwise I cannot give it access to the $or_list variable.

(`$thing_query` is the query that's being built over the course of this and other functions.)

```
elseif (strstr($column, 'or|')){
        //in format  or|=tablename-id=240,tablename-id=8
            $or_list = explode(',', $value);
            var_dump(explode(',', $value));
            $thing_query->where(function($q, $or_list)
            {
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($or_list as $or) {
                    $arr = explode('=', $or);
                    $col = $arr[0];
                    $val = $arr[1];
                    $col = str_replace('-', '.', $col);
                    if($count == 0){
                       $q->where($col, '=', $val);
                    } else {
                       $q->or_where($col, '=', $val);
                    }

                    $count++;
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$thing_query->where(function($q) use($or_list)
{
...
```

http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html

Comment: every day in every way i am getting better