# How to use LIKE operator with AND operator in a query with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am a newbe about Laravel.
In the View I have a form with a dropdown menu that have many participants.
When the form is submitted the value of the participant (for example "7") goes to the controller, in which there is a query that should retrieve from the DB all the rows that have "7" in the column "id_participants".
Unfortunately the column "id_participants" has strings in this format "3;8;65;4;34".

I tried in many ways to solve this problem, but I was only able to retrieve the rows that have a record equals to "7".

```
public function fetch_table(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'participants' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required|date',
        'end_date' => 'required|date',
        'rooms' => 'required',
    ]);

    $start_date = $request['start_date'];
    $end_date = $request['end_date'];
    $participants = $request['participants'];
    $room = $request['rooms'];

    $rooms = Room::all();
    $users = User::all()->where('is_active', '1')->sortBy('surname'); 
    $meetings = Meeting::all()
    ->where('is_active', '1')
    ->where('id_room', $room)
    ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
    ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
    ->where('id_participants', $participants); //look at here

    return view('reportArea', compact('users','rooms','meetings'));
}
```

So finally I should be able to do a similar query:
`SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE id_participants like "%;7" or id_participants like "7;%" or id_participants like "%;7;%" or id_participants = 7`.
Obviously 7 is only an example... the query should be dynamic.
Is anyone able to help me?

UPDATE:

I solved the issue after many attempts substituting the "meetings" query with the following:

```
$meetings = DB::table('meetings')
            ->where('is_active', '1')
            ->where('id_room', $room)
            ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
            ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
            ->where(function ($query) use($participants) {
              $query->where('id_participants', $participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants)
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', $participants.';%')
                    ->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants.';%');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Is changing `id_participants` data format an option to you?

Comment: @elias No because in a meeting could participate many participants, not only one. I cannot imagine another data format.

Comment: Create a second table for storing participants. Use laravel relationships properly and you will avoid a lot of code.

Comment: You really should be using a many to many relationship. In general avoid adding arrays, objects etc to the database unless completely necessary, as the problem you are facing now is the reason we separate this. Check out database normalization, laravel foreign key migrations & relationships as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can [nest your queries](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#nested-where): (related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653216/combining-and-or-eloquent-query-in-laravel))

```
$meetings = Meeting::all()
    ->where('is_active', '1')
    ->where('id_room', $room)
    ->where('date', '<', $end_date)
    ->where('date', '>', $start_date)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('id_participants', $participants);
        $query->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants);
        $query->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', $participants.';%');
        $query->orWhere('id_participants', 'like', '%;'.$participants.';%');
    });
```

**However** - as the comments point out - storing relations like this is very inefficient. I suggest you create a separate many-to-many table for participants. (it seems that's how they would be related)

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: are you sure that it works? I saw this error copying and pasting your code: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given `